# Deleting line numbers from a text file in java

Tags: java

The written code does not delete the desired line numbers ( that are three numeric values e.g., 001, 002....999), instead, it is deleting the whole document, except the first line.(showing the first line excluding the 000 from the first line). It is required to delete the first column of the entire text file that is of form 000, 001,002, 003, and so on. 
Here is the code that I am trying to execute.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class delete{

public static void main(String[] args){

try{ 

 File file = new File("abc.txt");  // create File object to read from
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);       // create scanner to read

 while(scanner.hasNextLine()){  // while there is a next line

 // hasNextLine() && 

     String line = scanner.nextLine();  // line = that next line
     char []ch = line.toCharArray();
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(line);

     // replace a character
     String newLine = ""; 
     for(int i = 0; i < line.length();i++){

             if((scanner.hasNextLine()) && (Character.isDigit(ch[i]))){
               // delete three characters and go to next line 
               char chr = ' ';
               sb.setCharAt(0,chr);                  
               sb.setCharAt(1,chr);
               sb.setCharAt(2,chr);
               scanner.nextLine();
               newLine = sb.toString();

           } 

        }

      // print to another file.
      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("abcd.txt"); // create file to write to
      writer.println(newLine);
      writer.flush();
      writer.close();
      scanner.close();
         }
     }catch (Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about my first 2 answers. Your question was unclear before, but now it is clear. Thank you. I have posted a correct answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling scanner.nextLine() within the for loop so it loops through the whole document without ever adding anything to the print writer. The reason the document only has the first line is you are constantly slamming newLine to be sb.toString() which never changes from when you declared it at the beginning.

You do not need the inner for loop at all because the outer while loop is iterating through each line. Just iterate through these lines and check if the first character is a digit and replace if so.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. You targeted _one_ problem(and there are many), but you did not attempt to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You have edited your question, and now it is more clear, thank you. To start, you have 3 loops that all do the same thing. I have simplified, indented 4 spaces(not 2), and shortened your code, like so. Line by line descriptions included:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try { 
        File file = new File("abc.txt"); //change to the location of your file
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("abcd.txt"); //change to where you would like your file to be
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {  //if statement and for loop are useless
            String line = scanner.nextLine(); //increments line
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(line); //makes line a sequence of char's
            String newLine; //used for printing to file
            char chr = ' '; //creates char equal to a space
            sb.setCharAt(0, chr); //replaces first,           
            sb.setCharAt(1,chr); //second,
            sb.setCharAt(2,chr); // and third char's with ' '
            newLine = sb.toString();
            writer.println(newLine); //prints the line without numers 
            writer.flush(); //flushes the stream
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) { //in case the file is not found
        ex.printStackTrace(); //prints the error
    }//end catch
}//end main
```